# Foreign Key Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create 3 models ; `Person`, `Address` and `Anniversy`. The plan is to have one address and one anniversy for each person. But each address and anniversy can have multiple persons.

So far I have the following, but I think the `OneToMany(foreign key)` relationships maybe the wrong way round. i.e each address can have one person but each person can have multiple addresses.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

class Address(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.address)

class Anniversy(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    anniversy = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.anniversy)
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You create the relationships the other way around; add foreign keys to the `Person` type to create a Many-to-One relationship:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    anniversary = models.ForeignKey(
        "Anniversary", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.ForeignKey(
        "Address", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Address(models.Model):
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    line2 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    postalcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Anniversary(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
```

I used string names for the other models so they can still be defined after, or you can define the `Person` model last.

Any one person can only be connected to *one* address and *one* anniversary, but addresses and anniversaries can be referenced from multiple `Person` entries.

`Anniversary` and `Address` objects will be given a reverse, backwards relationship too; by default it'll be called `person_set` but you can configure a different name if you need to. See Following [relationships "backward"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) in the queries documentation.

Comment: Address and Anniversary must define before person class.

Comment: @namjoo: or, use strings to name the models. But yes, thanks for pointing out the error, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 7):

I would advise, it is slightly better practise to use string model references for `ForeignKey` relationships if utilising an app based approach to seperation of logical concerns .

So, expanding on Martijn Pieters' answer:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    anniversary = models.ForeignKey(
        'app_label.Anniversary', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.ForeignKey(
        'app_label.Address', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Address(models.Model):
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    line2 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    postalcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Anniversary(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: what is App Label

Comment: @perymerdeka The name of the app, as given in INSTALLED_APPS. :)

Comment: Within the same module, you can omit the app label: `"Anniversary"` and `"Address"` work too.

Comment: does this also help avoid Cyclic Dependency Error when you are trying to foreign key two tables in different files that import each other?

Comment: @YashKumarVerma Exactly.