# field defines relation with model as abstract or uninstalled

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, abstract

I'm trying to set a foreign and keep receiving this error when I try to sync the database or run the program.

```
class OffenseStats(models.Model):
    passingYards = models.IntegerField()
    passingTouchdowns = models.IntegerField()
    rushingTouchdowns = models.IntegerField()
    receivingTouchdowns = models.IntegerField()
    receivingYards = models.IntegerField()
    rushingYards = models.IntegerField()
    yardsAfterCatch = models.IntegerField()
    catches = models.IntegerField()
    pancakes = models.IntegerField()
    sacksAllowed = models.IntegerField()
    puntReturnedTouchdowns = models.IntegerField()
    kickReturnedTouchdowns = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return 'ID: %s', self.statID


class StudentAccount(PersonAccount):

    highSchool = models.CharField(max_length=Account.MAX_SIZE)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=Account.MAX_SIZE)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=Account.MAX_SIZE)
    article = models.ManyToManyField(studentArticle)
    stats = models.ManyToManyField(studentStats)
    video = models.ManyToManyField(studentVideo)
    references = models.ManyToManyField(studentReferences)
    recruitingBoard = models.ManyToManyField(studentRecuritingBoard)
    studentMessage = models.ManyToManyField(Messages)
    offenseStat = models.ForeignKey('OffenseStats')
```

All of the questions I've seen previously have been repaired by spelling something correctly or importing a model. Both models are in the same file. Not sure if I just don't have a strong enough grasp

Answer (score 0):

Going by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663523/foreign-key-django-model) your problem is the single quotes around offensive stats. You want the primary key from `OffenseStats`, not the string "OffenseStats"

Your last line of code should look like this:
        offenseStat = models.ForeignKey(OffenseStats)