# Python, Django : Foreignkey accross apps is not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

Python :3.6.2  Django : 1.11.4

We are trying to use foreignkey across apps.  Address is consumed by both customer and agent.  We are also using inline frameset.  If I put all this in one app,  it is working fine including inline frameset.  If I split into multiple apps,  I have this error.  Please see the pictures below.

[Foreignkey error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVViX.png)

```
File "C:/Users/palak/Desktop/mergemodels\apps\sharedmodels\models.py", line         15, in <module>
class Address(models.Model):
File "C:/Users/palak/Desktop/mergemodels\apps\sharedmodels\models.py", line 16, in Address
    agent = models.Foreignkey('apps.agent.Agent')
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

[Project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qx09.png)

```
<BLOCKQUOTE>
```

apps (Folder) 
     agent (app) 
             models.py 
      customer (app) 
            models.py 
      sharedmodels(app) 
            models.py

Please note the apps the above folder structure.

sharedmodels/models.py

```
from django.db import models
#from apps.agent.models import Agent

class ContactInfo(models.Model):
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
class Location(models.Model):
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
class Address(models.Model):
    #agent = models.Foreignkey(Agent)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

agent/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from apps.sharedmodels.models import Location, Address, ContactInfo

class Agent(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
    address = models.Foreignkey(Address)
    contactinfo = models.OneToOneField(ContactInfo)
```

customer/models.py

```
from django.db import models
#from apps.agent.models import Agent, Address
from apps.sharedmodels.models import ContactInfo, Address

class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    #address = models.OneToOneField(Address)
    contactinfo = models.OneToOneField(ContactInfo)
    address = models.Foreignkey(Address)
```

Settings.py - installapps section

```
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'apps.customer',
    'apps.agent',
    'apps.sharedmodels',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: Any immediate help is really appreciated on this

Comment: Could you type your error and not a link to your error, same for folder structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign Key Django Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663523/foreign-key-django-model)

Answer (score 0):

Set Foreign Key as string [foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

```
agent = models.Foreignkey('agent.Agent')
#                         ^^^^^^^
```

sharedmodels/models.py

```
from django.db import models


class ContactInfo(models.Model):
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Location(models.Model):
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)


class Address(models.Model):
    agent = models.ForeignKey('agent.Agent', related_name='addresses')
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

agent/models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Agent(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.ManyToManyField('sharedmodels.Location')
    address = models.ForeignKey('sharedmodels.Address', related_name='agents')
    contactinfo = models.OneToOneField('sharedmodels.ContactInfo')


from django.db import models
```

customer/models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    contactinfo = models.OneToOneField('sharedmodels.ContactInfo')
    address = models.ForeignKey('sharedmodels.Address')
```

Comment: Thank you much for the response.   We have tried that.  We have even tried 'apps.agent.Agent'.  No luck.

Comment: did you try without `import`? all your FK as string

Comment: Here latest error without import and FK as string. 'agent.Agent'   File "C:/Users/palak/Desktop/mergemodels\apps\sharedmodels\models.py", line 15, in <module>
    class Address(models.Model):
  File "C:/Users/palak/Desktop/mergemodels\apps\sharedmodels\models.py", line 16, in Address
    agent = models.Foreignkey('apps.agent.Agent')
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: added more details

Comment: Thank you much Bear Brown.  Your code snippets helped us to move on from the foreignkey error.   Great patience and efforts!

Comment: glad to help you, you should accept the answer to let future searchers know it solved your problem.