# Add an exception for model relationship of a specific object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am kind a newbie in django and python. In my app each user is assigned many projects but each project has a specific user. What I am trying to achieve is to show to a user that never created any project, a project demo.

I tried that when a user register he is directly assigned the demo project but since a project can have only one user is does not work when another sign in..

Is it possible to create an exception to a model attribute et to specify that for a specific Project can have multiple users ?

Here is my code: 
Project model :

```
class Project(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey('registration.MyUser', blank=True, null=True)
    candidat_answers = models.ManyToManyField('survey.response')
    applicant = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="applicant")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs={'pk1': self.pk})
```

Register a user :

```
def registerManager(request):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    registered = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        Manager_form = ManagerForm(data=request.POST)

        if Manager_form.is_valid():
            user = Manager_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.is_manager = True
            user.save()
            registered = True
            login(request, user)
            demoProject = Project.objects.get(name="Project SoftScores")
            request.user.project_set.add(demoProject)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website:hr_index'))
        else:
            print("Error!")
    else:
        Manager_form = ManagerForm()
    return render(request, 'HR_registration_form.html',
                  {'Manager_form': Manager_form,
                   'registered': registered})
```

Error message: 
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:

```
website.DemoProject.applicant: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'DemoProject.applicant' clashes with reverse ac
cessor for 'Project.applicant'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'DemoProject.applicant' or 'Project.app
licant'.
website.DemoProject.applicant: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'DemoProject.applicant' clashes with reverse
query name for 'Project.applicant'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'DemoProject.applicant' or 'Project.app
licant'.
website.Project.applicant: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Project.applicant' clashes with reverse accessor f
or 'DemoProject.applicant'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.applicant' or 'DemoProject.app
licant'.
website.Project.applicant: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Project.applicant' clashes with reverse query na
me for 'DemoProject.applicant'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project.applicant' or 'DemoProject.app
licant'.

WARNINGS:
website.DemoProject.project_hr_admin: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
```

Edited Code:

```
class BaseProject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey('registration.MyUser', blank=True, null=True)
    candidat_answers = models.ManyToManyField('survey.response')
    applicant = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="applicant")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs={'pk1': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Project(BaseProject):
    def has_member_responses(self, result=None):
        try:
            x = Project.objects.get(id=self.id).team_id.members.all()

            for i in x:
                result = 1
                if i.response_set.exists():
                    result = result * True
                else:
                    result = result * False
            return result
        except AttributeError:
            return False


class DemoProject(BaseProject):
    project_hr_admin = models.ManyToManyField('registration.MyUser', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: One project can have multiple user. So you might need to create one Foreign Key for this. Have a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663523/foreign-key-django-model

Comment: project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey('registration.MyUser', blank=True, null=True) does not mean the opposite ? that a user can have multiple projects . ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can handle this, but the cleanest In my opinion is to create an abstract `BaseProject` model and make that the parent class of the `Project` model and a `DemoProject` model.

```
class BaseProject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey('registration.MyUser', blank=True, null=True)
    candidat_answers = models.ManyToManyField('survey.response')
    applicant = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="applicant")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs={'pk1': self.pk})
```

Now create the `DemoProject` as a child of `BaseProject`

```
class DemoProject(BaseProject):

    project_hr_admin = models.ManyToManyField('registration.MyUser', blank=True, null=True)
```

Then you can update your registration code to use the new model.

```
def registerManager(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        Manager_form = ManagerForm(data=request.POST)

        if Manager_form.is_valid():
            user = Manager_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.is_manager = True
            user.save()
            registered = True
            login(request, user)
            demo_project = DemoProject.objects.get(name="Demo Project")
            request.user.project_set.add(demoProject)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website:hr_index'))
        else:
            print("Error!")
    else:
        Manager_form = ManagerForm()
    return render(request, 'HR_registration_form.html',
              {'Manager_form': Manager_form,
               'registered': registered})
```

This way, you've seperated the two entities and managed to preserve the behaviour/identitiy of the `DemoProject` (A `DemoProject` is still a `Project`).

This also means you can modify the main `Project` model without affecting the `DemoProject` model.

Your main `Project` model should look like this now

```
class Project(BaseProject):
     # any custom stuff that's unique to a project
    pass
```

Comment: is it inheritance ?

Comment: Yes, it's inheritance. but there's a special catch to it in Django. If the `BaseProject` isn't an abstract model you won't be able to override the field so `abstract = True` is necessary.

Comment: I just got a big error .. I edited my post .. I have conflicts ... @danidee

Comment: I used '%(app_label)s' and '%(class)s if someone else need it !
Danidee best answer thx men !